# Lost drivers after a update on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: drivers, sound, updates, ethernet

So the other day I updated my Ubuntu (was just a tiny update, nothing major). Everything went fine, I was working something on Kodi, so nothing OS related. So I normally shut down the PC, and the next day I started it up again, the first thing I noticed is that while booting I got that terminal-looking screen and it says that it's just checking through some files and that I would have to run "fsck" manually on /dev/sda1 (the +- 300mb partition), and I did. After a restart, it booted normally.

Next thing I noticed is that it was a lot slower than usual. After that I realized that I couldn't connect to my network (I tried different ways of connecting, also worked around the network, router etc. and still couldn't connect), also my sound didn't work, anywhere (on HDMI nor 3.5mm output). And the gpu drivers weren't working, noticed it because everything was laggy, the animations didn't work, and Kodi's animations were a lot more laggy. USB ports work fine.

I'm really out of ideas, I tried doing fsck using the terminal, but never succeeded.

Asus P5K-SE
Core2Quad Q8200
6GB DDR2 RAM
low spec HD6000 AMD GPU

I'm currently thinking about reinstalling the whole system, but that wouldn't be good since I did a lot things on my current Ubuntu which are pain in the ass to redo. Also I tried using a different PC, but the HDD from the PC where I used Ubuntu - same thing, sound, ethernet and GPU drivers aren't responding.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: here's the output of `free -h`
[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bl1Gw.png)

Edit 2: here's the output from the terminal  [Here](https://paste.ofcode.org/J7zbXmGeQQEcRmEqDyHAKZ)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To manually check your filesystem with fsck...

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- open a `terminal` window
- type `sudo fdisk -l`
- identify the /dev/XXXX device name for your "Linux Filesystem"
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/XXXX` # replacing XXXX with the number you found earlier
- repeat the fsck command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

**Update #1:**

```
Note: do NOT abort a bad block scan!

Note: do NOT bad block a SSD

Note: backup your important files FIRST!
```

`sudo e2fsck -fcky /dev/sdb1` # read-only test

or

`sudo e2fsck -fccky /dev/sdb1` # non-destructive read/write test **(recommended)**

The -k is important, because it saves the previous bad block table, and adds any new bad blocks to that table. Without -k, you loose all of the prior bad block information.

The -fccky parameter...

```
   -f     Force checking even if the file system seems clean.

   -c     This option causes e2fsck to use badblocks(8) program  to  do  a
          read-only  scan  of  the device in order to find any bad blocks.
          If any bad blocks are found, they are added  to  the  bad  block
          inode  to  prevent them from being allocated to a file or direc‐
          tory.  If this option is specified twice,  then  the  bad  block
          scan will be done using a non-destructive read-write test.

   -k     When combined with the -c option, any existing bad blocks in the
          bad blocks list are preserved, and any new bad blocks  found  by
          running  badblocks(8)  will  be added to the existing bad blocks
          list.

   -y     Assume  an answer of `yes' to all questions; allows e2fsck to be
          used non-interactively.  This option may not be specified at the
          same time as the -n or -p options.
```

Comment: No, that did not work. Same as usual, and the output of "fsck" is just that I wound (or scanned) some files, and doesn't offer anything else.

Comment: @MarinSebesic  It won't do anything if it didn't find anything wrong. The output of the command should be approx 5-6 lines of scanning info. But on the next reboot, you shouldn't see the message about having to do a manual scan. Correct? Edit your question and show me the `terminal` output of `free -h`.

Comment: @MarinSebesic Thanks for the `free -h` information. Trying to determine what's wrong and I need more data. Please start the `Disks` app, select the `SMART Data & Tests` from the "hamburger" menu icon. View the data, take a screenshot, and edit that into your question for me. Go ahead and run the tests too. Thanks! Be sure to start comments to me with "@heynnema" or I may miss them.

Comment: Here it is: imgur.com/a/pAPgBzJ

Comment: @MarinSebesic OK, you've got some bad blocks on the HDD. Before we attend to that, we need to do two things. Check that you've got the latest BIOS. In `terminal` do `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and that will tell you your current version. Then go to the ASUS web site and see if there's a newer BIOS for your model #. Second, backup all of your important files, as we're going to do a bad block scan next. Report back. Remember to start comments to me with "@heynnema" or I may miss them.

Comment: @MarinSebesic Also, edit your question to include the `terminal` output of `sudo fdisk -l` and `df`. Use copy/paste please.

Comment: The output is up there, the BIOS is up to date. Note: the "sda1,2,3" can be ignored since they're not being used while using Ubuntu. (I'm not being able to tag you, adding the tag doesn't work, after commenting the tag disappears.)

Comment: @MarinSebesic I've added Update #1 in my answer. Please do the recommended scan. This may take a few hours. Report back. Ah yes, since you're commenting in response to my answer, you don't need the tag.

Comment: status please...

Comment: I really do feel bad saying this, but, I wanted to do the procedure, but it simply took too long. I felt like the drive was already badly damaged, and that process of getting bad would just keep on getting worse. At the end I decided to just get a new drive. But I'm really glad that somebody out there tried to help, but it's just a bad drive. Thanks again.